# Does only BIOS define how F1-12 and media keys behave?

Tags: linux, keyboard, bios, thinkpad, fn-key

I use a Lenovo ThinkPad E430 laptop running linux mint. 
By default the media keys work without the Fn key and the F1-12 work like Fn+F1-12.
I inverted them in BIOS, so I don't have to press the Fn key when for example I want to close a window. I also inverted the Crtl and Fn keys, because the guys from Lenovo decided that the Ctrl key shouldn't be at the corner of the keyboard and I think that's ridiculous. But that's not the problem.

On fresh boot everything works as I want. But in longer use (I don't shut down my laptop every day-I use suspend) the media and F-keys revert back. The strange thing is that does not happen with the Ctrl and Fn. They are always inverted, no matter how long is the session. On reboot media keys are back to their secondary stage.

So my question: Is there something in the kernel of the OS (or some other software) that manages the keyboard and the behaviour of function keys? And if there is, why it's not subjected to the BIOS (I mean in my case)? And how can I synchronize them?

Comment: BIOS is software.  It can be written to only response to certain keys.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: Well in my case I think there is some kind of conflict between BIOS and other software. My best guess was linux kernel. So the question is what could cause the conflict? Why the keys are inverted at boot and in hour or two they revert back to default, regardless of the BIOS config? And what can I do to make this permanent? (btw I want to apologize if I can't explain myself very well. My english is not that good.)

Comment: At the point BIOS is looking for those keys no other software can be running so no it's not a conflict with other software

Comment: Than how come it loses the reversing config for the F-kys over time and not the one for the Ctrl and Fn keys. Because with the F-keys it happens every session, but it never has with Ctrl, not even once.
I forgot to mention that I've had that problem for an year or so. Ever since I bought the laptop. During that time I've used different versions of LM.

Comment: Your first sentence does not make sense please clarify and update your question but I stand by my statement bios is before the kernel is even starting to be loaded

Comment: Yeah, ok. Maybe I didn't explain the case so well.

Comment: I go to BIOS. There are two options:
1) swap the Ctrl and Fn keys positions. No problem here. 
2) swap the F1-12 and media-keys, so that media-keys have to work in combination with Fn. Here's the problem. At boot - BIOS' configuration takes place. Two hours (of Internet browsing) later - it's like I've never chose that option.
The above 2 options look identical to me.
Why the first option stays permanent and the second reverts back to default?
If my question is still unclear, I'll stop asking. And I'm sorry that I've wasted your time.

Comment: @viko I think it is a reasonable question to ask. I had a similar issue with swapping my ``ctrl`` and ``capslock`` keys and never really got to the bottom of the problem. It could be anything really... One option would be to look into remapping you keyboard on the OS level. ``xmodmap`` could help, I believe.

Comment: **Step 1**: ensure you have the latest BIOS version. If not, then update to latest. If the problem persists at the latest version, then **Step 2**: search forums.lenovo.com for the issue and if you cannot find it, I stringly suggest you to post also there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At most features of built-on keyboards like <kbd>Fn</kbd> only BIOS is in the control. Most often the OS does not even know about presence of this special modifier key. Some computer models make special features available to their drivers running under the OS, but this is not always true.

Example:

- some features are reachable: in utility supplied by manufacturer of your laptop, you can control keyboard backlight behavior (always on / always off / automatic)
- on the other hand, I haven't seen the case where keypress of <kbd>Fn</kbd> was visible to keyboard routines in OS. It is completely hidden from the OS.

In your case I strongly believe this is only the BIOS problem. You can also test it by some neat procedures, e.g. keep your system untouched for few hours (you can also disable scheduled tasks etc.) to ensure no application was launched which could affect the behavior.